# how to retrieve json files from url inside a text file

Tags: json, linux, bash, curl, web-scraping

I have to check the json data from an url using curl
`curl -H "User-agent: 'your bot 0.1'" url.json | jq`
this code is working

i wanted try this for a .txt file containing 200 url
like these

https://www.reddit.com/user/wanderer_007_.json

https://www.reddit.com/....

https://www.reddit.com/....

https://www.reddit.com/....

https://www.reddit.com/....

these are just examples. but whenever I give the text file as an input

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
   curl -H "User-agent: 'your bot 0.1'" $name | jq 
done < test001.txt


curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

but if I try to use the url individually it is working as intended

Comment: should be $name instead of url.json? I copied the code and didn't get the error

Comment: i used the $name only , but it didn't work for me, i have edited the question now

Comment: Still I didn't get the error. You will get an error from `jq` because `reddit.com` didnt return a json response(`parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 10`). Your code should work if the urls in the text file are requests that will receive json-responses. Seems that the urls that you post(reddit.com) are not the real urls, can you post the real ones?

Comment: the urls are from reddit only they are like https://www.reddit.com/user/wanderer_007_.json this will get the json data i need

Comment: I got the desired output using your code and that type of urls, are you sure that your test001.txt file contains what you thinks that it contains?

Comment: file does contain the url in what i expected

Comment: it worked on another device  and thank you very much for giving me courage to believe in myself

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the filename in curl command with double quotes:

```sh
curl -H "User-agent: 'your bot 0.1'" "$name" | jq
```

The error may be due to Bash interpreting some wierd characters in URLs specially. For example space in the URL may cause $name to split into 2 command-line arguments making curl unable to parse its inputs.

Comment: i tried this also but I don't know what the hell is happening with my virtual box

Comment: thank you it got solved , the problem was with the device i was using